# Ошибка в QT main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd6): undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'

Tags: c++, qt5

Пытаюсь создать тривиальное приложение на QT: от нажатий кнопки увеличивается счетчик, если увеличивается счетчик, отпечатывает текущее значение в QLabel.

Внезапная ошибка, не могу решить, что делать.

Добавлять виртуальный деструктор пробовал.
Переставлять версию QT - нет еще.

**О версиях:**

```
$ qmake --version
```

выдает:

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

**conn.pro файл содержит следующее:**

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += core gui

TARGET = conn
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

**main.cpp файл содержит следующее:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    double i_;

public:
    virtual ~Counter()
    {

    }
    Counter() : QObject(), i_(0)
    {
    }


public slots:
    void slot_incCounter();

signals:
    void goodbye(){}
    void counterChanged(double){}
};

void Counter::slot_incCounter() {
    emit counterChanged(++i_);
    if (i_ == 5) {
        emit goodbye();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication my_app(argc, argv);

    QLabel label1("label i created");
    label1.show();

    QPushButton button1("press me");
    button1.show();

    Counter counter1;

    QObject::connect(&button1, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &counter1, SLOT(slot_incCounter()));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(counterChanged(double a)),
                     &label1, SLOT(setNum(double a)));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(goodbye()),
                     &my_app, SLOT(quit()));

    return my_app.exec();
}
```

Запускаю так:

```
qmake && make && ./conn
```

Далее вывод ошибки такой:

```
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o conn main.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd6): undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:144: recipe for target 'conn' failed
make`:` *** [conn] Error 1
```

Как быть?

Comment: попробуй вынести класс Counter в отдельный файл

Comment: причем объявление класса нужно вынести в h файл.

Comment: Сделано, не спасло.

Comment: Внезапно я удалил Q_OBJECT в исходном коде и оно хотя бы скомпилилось. Но пока что не работает.

Comment: если класс сделать без Q_OBJECT, то оно конечно скомпилируется. Но сигналы/слоты для этого класса работать не будут.

Comment: qmake запустите принудительно, после этого собирайте. Q_OBJECT верните обратно

Comment: я уже ведь показывал как запускаю его.   И make clean делал. И все равно vtable не находит

Comment: Сорри, сделал заново более аккуратно, вынес класс в .h-файл, вернул Q_OBJECT, все заработало.  KoVadim, спасибо!

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Ошибка «undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'» в классе с Q_OBJECT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/796894/208074)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Что нужно было сделать:**

**1. Перенести Counter в файл Counter.h
 2. Никогда не писать определения для signal'ов.**

Рабочий код:
**main.cpp:**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Counter.h"



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication my_app(argc, argv);

    QLabel label1("1");
    label1.show();

    QPushButton button1("press me");
    button1.show();

    Counter counter1;

    QObject::connect(&button1, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &counter1, SLOT(slot_incCounter()));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(counterChanged(double)),
                     &label1, SLOT(setNum(double)));

    QObject::connect(&counter1, SIGNAL(goodbye()),
                     &my_app, SLOT(quit()));

    return my_app.exec();
}
```

**Counter.h:**

```
#ifndef COUNTER_H
#define COUNTER_H

#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QObject>

class Counter : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    double i_;

public:
    virtual ~Counter()
    {
    }

    Counter() : QObject()
    {
    }


public slots:
    void slot_incCounter();

signals:
    void goodbye();
    void counterChanged(double);
};

#endif // COUNTER_H
```

**Counter.cpp:**

```
#include "Counter.h"


void Counter::slot_incCounter() {
    emit counterChanged(++i_);
    if (i_ == 5) {
        emit goodbye();
    }
}
```

Спасибо всем