# Ошибка «undefined reference to `vtable for Counter'» в классе с Q_OBJECT

Tags: c++, qt

Когда:

1. Я меняю структуру класса (добавляю/удаляю методы или изменяю их сигнатуру);
2. Этот класс унаследован от `QObject`;
3. Внутри него используется `Q_OBJECT`,

при дальнейшей компиляции я получаю ошибку:

> undefined reference to `vtable for ИмяКласса'

С чем это связано и как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что файлы проекта, а именно:

- все заголовочные файлы,
- `*.cpp`-файлы, внизу которых имеется строка `#include <имя-cpp-файла.moc>`

пропускаются через так называемый метаобъектный генератор, который генерирует для каждого класса с `Q_OBJECT` дополнительные объявления и определения и помещает их в отдельный `*.cpp`-файл. По ряду причин таблица виртуальных функций класса также попадает в тот файл.

Однако эти вспомогательные файлы не всегда обновляются при сборке после внесения изменений в исходный файл. Поэтому после каждого изменения класса необходимо очищать директорию сборки или удалять её.

Comment: *"эти вспомогательные файлы не всегда обновляются при сборке после внесения изменений в исходный файл"* в первую очередь говорит о неправильной настройке сборки.

Comment: Необязательно удалять всю директорию сборки, можно просто перезапустить qmake.\

Answer (score 2):

Поставил в настройках сборки checkbox запускать qmake при каждой сборке